# Excel VBA copy data into a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find the highest value in the second row of the '2G' sheet and paste it's entire column into the 'Daily2G' sheet. The first row of the '2G' sheet has the date and time (24 hour period).

The code also compares the date and only copies the data if the dates are different.

The code was working fine for the past two days, but it isn't working today. I can't figure out what the problem is. I would appreciate it if someone could take a look at the code and tell me where I'm going wrong.

The code works if I compare the values in any other row but I want to check the values only in the second row. Also the duplicate check is also not working, it was before today.

```
Sub Daily2G()
    Dim dailySht As Worksheet 'worksheet storing latest store activity
    Dim recordSht As Worksheet 'worksheet to store the highest period of each day
    Dim lColDaily As Integer ' Last column of data in the store activity sheet
    Dim lCol As Integer ' Last column of data in the record sheet
    Dim maxCustomerRng As Range ' Cell containing the highest number of customers
    Dim CheckForDups As Range ' Used to find duplicate dates on the record Sheet
    Dim maxCustomerCnt As Long ' value of highest customer count

    Set dailySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2G")
    Set recordSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily 2G")
    With recordSht
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    With dailySht
        lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        maxCustomerCnt = Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lColDaily)))
        Set maxCustomerRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not maxCustomerRng Is Nothing Then
        ' Check the Record Sheet to ensure the data is not already there
            Set CheckForDups = recordSht.Range(recordSht.Cells(1, 1), recordSht.Cells(1, lCol)).Find(What:=maxCustomerRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        ' If CheckForDups is Nothing then the date was not found on the record sheet. Therefore, copy the column
            If CheckForDups Is Nothing Then
                maxCustomerRng.EntireColumn.Copy
                recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            End If
        End If
    End With

    Set maxCustomerRng = Nothing
    Set dailySht = Nothing
    Set recordSht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Tell us what error you get on what line. Or what happens. Simply stating it doesn't work is too broad.

Comment: @Luuklag Excecuting the code works when it compares values in any other row apart from the second row which is what I'm trying to do. Nothing happens when comparing values in the second row. When it debugging mode, it shows that the correct value is selected in the second row but it does not past the its column.

Comment: @Luuklag yes I did and the correct value is matched. It just does not copy its column

Comment: What is the value of `maxCustomerCnt` when you step through with F8?

Comment: @Jeeped it shows the correct value/highest value which is what I'm trying to obtain.

Comment: @Jeeped the value of maxCustomerCnt returns the correct value when I step through it with F8 but the its column does not get copied to the Daily2G sheet.

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with the dupe check, but it looks like you are referring to row 1, and later an offset of -1, which would be row 0, which doesn't exist. Just thinkin out loud. `Set CheckForDups = recordSht.Range(recordSht.Cells(1, 1), recordSht.Cells(1, lCol)).Find(What:=maxCustomerRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)` I may be way off here, not sure if I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: Other than the point what @Mitch has raised, the code looks okay and it should work fine specially when you say that it works for other rows but not for row2 now. Can you share a sample workbook to see what could be the issue with it?

Comment: @Mitch I've removed the '-' and tried the code in a different sheet that it's working on but it still copies duplicates

Comment: @sktneer how do I share the workbook

Comment: Well you could try uploading it on Google Drive or DropBox and share the link here.

Comment: While uploading the file, don't forget to show your desired output on another sheet.

Comment: @sktneer here's a sample file on gdrive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ZE0Dd3Mbh2MEpjY2swTkFlRXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @sktneer the desired output is on the second sheet (Daily2G)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how and what are you trying to find as duplicate so changed a bit in the code so that if, as per the sample file, 3488.95 isn't found in row2 in Daily2G Sheet, the code will copy the column with Max value to the Daily2G sheet else it will skip.

Also, in the sample file, the Sheet name is "Daily2G" not "Daily 2G", so changed it in the code and you change it in your actual workbook as required.

The problem with your code is you have declared maxCustomerCnt as long whereas the values in row2 on 2G sheet are decimal values so the NaxCustomerRng will always be nothing.

Please give this a try...

```
Sub Daily2G()
    Dim dailySht As Worksheet 'worksheet storing latest store activity
    Dim recordSht As Worksheet 'worksheet to store the highest period of each day
    Dim lColDaily As Integer ' Last column of data in the store activity sheet
    Dim lCol As Integer ' Last column of data in the record sheet
    Dim maxCustomerRng As Range ' Cell containing the highest number of customers
    Dim CheckForDups As Range ' Used to find duplicate dates on the record Sheet
    Dim maxCustomerCnt As Double ' value of highest customer count

    Set dailySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2G")
    Set recordSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily2G")
    With recordSht
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    With dailySht
        lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        maxCustomerCnt = Round(Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lColDaily))), 2)
        Set maxCustomerRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not maxCustomerRng Is Nothing Then
        ' Check the Record Sheet to ensure the data is not already there
            Set CheckForDups = recordSht.Range(recordSht.Cells(2, 1), recordSht.Cells(2, lCol)).Find(What:=Round(maxCustomerRng.Value, 2), LookIn:=xlValues)
        ' If CheckForDups is Nothing then the date was not found on the record sheet. Therefore, copy the column
            If CheckForDups Is Nothing Then
                maxCustomerRng.EntireColumn.Copy
                recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            End If
        End If
    End With

    Set maxCustomerRng = Nothing
    Set dailySht = Nothing
    Set recordSht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Run the above code in the sample file you provided and if it works well, test it with your actual file after making required changes.

Comment: Thanks it works! But the check for duplicates isn't working

Comment: Based on your sample file and once the column is copied to the Daily2G, sheet if you run the code again, what will you consider as duplicate? The proposed code will look for the max value found in row2 on 2G sheet (3488.95 in this case) in row2 on Daily2G sheet and if it finds it, it will consider it as a duplicate and will not copy the same entire column again to the Daily2G sheet. Are you trying to achieve something else when you check for duplicates?

Comment: e.g. if you run the proposed code multiple times with the same sample file without making any changes in row2 on 2G sheet, it will not copy the column H more than once.

Comment: Actually it works fine. Thanks for your help! and have a good weekend!!

Comment: @aab You're welcome! Glad it worked. Thanks and wish you same. :)